# Is it possible to limit NetworkManager to a set of named interfaces?

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager

NetworkManager is great for managing my wireless device, but I don't want it touching the virtual devices I create for network experiments (which I use with VMs or containers). I'd really like a way to tell NetworkManager to only manage wlan0 (for example), but the docs don't seem to indicate that's possible.

Has anyone come up with a way to do this?

Alternatively, is there a decent tool for managing wireless networks in Ubuntu that would behave this way? I'd prefer something a bit nicer than ifup/ifdown.

Comment: OK, I've temporarily gone with this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

It's not as nice as NM, but it only does wireless.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.10 and before, NetworkManager correctly ignored interfaces created by VirtualBox (vboxnet*). In 15.04 it insists on managing them and solutions here do not work. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1485558 . In the meantime, any solution working on 15.04 would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

Add your interface(-s) to /etc/network/interfaces . NetworkManager checks this file.
See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321380/disable-network-manager-for-a-particular-interface

Comment: Unfortunately I'm making a lot of interfaces so this isn't really tenable.

Comment: Regex is your friend. :) See https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/microkernel/mach/gnumach/ports/xen/networking_configuration.html